# LINQ method to load child Entity that includes some of Parent's navigational properties and only selected Grand Child 's records

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I've three tables `Site_Report` `Report_Asset` and `Asset_Calcert` with One-to-Many relationship between them, as shown.

[image: Relationship diagram]

I want to load a child entity as a model i.e `Report_Asset` which should include some of the parent's properties. And also, from grand child's collection navigation property, I want to load single record using a condition.

*First Attempt* - This leads to an error.

```
Report_Asset model;
model = ctx.Report_Asset
           .Include(i => i.Site_Report)
           .Include(i => i.Site_Report.Handled_By)
           .Include(i => i.Site_Report.Published_By)
           .Include(i => i.Asset_Calcerts.Select(b => b.asset_calcert_id == assetCalcertId))
           .FirstOrDefault();
```

> **ERROR:** The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.

*Second Attempt* - By starting form grandchild Entity and including the parents. This approach does load the result set, but it only contains the child entity i.e `Report_Asset` and no record from `Asset_Calcert` collection and null for `Site_Report`.

```
Report_Asset model;
model = ctx.Asset_Calcert.Include(i => i.Report_Asset)
                                 .Include(i => i.Report_Asset.Site_Report.Handled_By)
                                 .Include(i => i.Report_Asset.Site_Report.Published_By)
                                 .Where(i => i.asset_calcert_id == assetCalcertId)
                                 .Select(i => i.Report_Asset).FirstOrDefault();
```

I've set `Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false` in DbContext().

Need direction, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to query and return an entity, it's parent, and then a sub-set of it's children.  You can use EF to query this, but only by reducing your query into a desired structure. If you return a Report_Asset, it can include a reference to it's parent easily enough, but it will always reference it's complete set of children, EF does not filter child sets at the entity level.

It's best to look at exactly what fields you want from each entity and select a structure containing just those, but at a very basic level, this should give you what you want:

```
var model = ctx.Report_Asset
    .Select( x = > new 
    {
       Report_Asset = x,
       Site_Report = x.Site_Report,
       Handled_By = x.Site_Report.Handled_By,
       Published_By = x.Site_Report.Published_By,
       Asset_Calcerts = x.Assert_Calcerts.Where(c => c.asset_calcert_id == assetCalcertId).ToList()
    }).FirstOrDefault();
```

The calcert check looks to be looking for a specific, single cert, so this might be better as:

```
var model = ctx.Report_Asset
    .Select( x = > new 
    {
       Report_Asset = x,
       Site_Report = x.Site_Report,
       Handled_By = x.Site_Report.Handled_By,
       Published_By = x.Site_Report.Published_By,
       Asset_Calcert = x.Assert_Calcerts.SingleOrDefailt(c => c.asset_calcert_id == assetCalcertId)
    }).FirstOrDefault();
```

If you were looking to load only report assets that had a matching Calcert, with the parent and the applicable calcert:

```
var model = ctx.Report_Asset
    .Where(x => x.Asset_Calcerts.Any(c => c.asset_calcert_id == assetCalcertId))
    .Select( x = > new 
    {
       Report_Asset = x,
       Site_Report = x.Site_Report,
       Handled_By = x.Site_Report.Handled_By,
       Published_By = x.Site_Report.Published_By,
       Asset_Calcert = x.Asset_Calcerts.SingleOrDefailt(c => c.asset_calcert_id == assetCalcertId)
    }).FirstOrDefault();
```

In all cases I would recommend adding an `OrderBy` clause before the `FirstOrDefault` to ensure a predictable order is used.

The caveat of this approach is that if you access the returned model's entities and start drilling down through their references, you will still trigger lazy loads from the database. For instance if I use:

`model.Report_Asset.Asset_Calcerts`

for instance, this will still lazy load the related entities for that report asset, and list *all* calcerts  for that asset. The filtered set/match is eager loaded into the model.Asset_Calcert(s), not the returned Model_Asset entity.

Generally though you are better off using `Select` to just retrieve the properties you care about from the various entities, rather than attempting to select entire entities or entity graphs. This forgoes the need for using `Include`, just tell EF exactly what you want from the entity graph and it will build an SQL statement to efficiently retrieve just that information.

Comment: Thanks Steve, The first two approach appears to load 0 AssetCalcerts, unless we filter it like in third approach.

Comment: Yeah, I kinda guessed that was the intention so I'd added the 3rd approach because the original just took an arbitrary Report_Asset which may not necessarily have had a matching AssetCalcert. The 3rd approach checks for a first ReportAsset that does have that calcert. You should still consider adding an `OrderBy` clause if you want to use `FirstOrDefault` to ensure it is using a consistent ordering. It may appear to work when there are minimal records, but later with more records it could pick a record other than the one you expect.

Comment: asset_Calcert_id is primary key in AssetCalcert table that will always return a single record from collection. That's why didn't find the need to adding orderby clause. Thanks for your help again.

Comment: I've one question though, from the selected AssetCalcert how could I include any of its navigational property ?

Comment: AFAIK `Include` won't work with this, as you'll essentially need to select those entities explicitly like I did with Handled_By & Published_By. The better approach is to look at what fields, from all applicable entities, your view model actually needs and define a view model structure which selects just those fields. Then there is no need to include dependencies, just select the properties from them into the viewmodel(s). You may only want one or two properties from a dependency so it's more efficient to just select them rather than the whole dependency.

Answer (score 0):

when using more then 1 level it is better to use the string option.
if you dont want to use string you will need to do select for the levels greater then 1.

```
Report_Asset model;
model = ctx.Report_Asset
           .Include("Site_Report")
           .Include("Site_Report.Handled_By")
           .Include("Site_Report.Published_By")
           .Include("Asset_Calcerts")
           .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Asset_Calcerts.Any(y => y.asset_calcert_id == assetCalcertId);
```

Comment: I've tried it, It's loading all of the `Asset_Calcerts` in the result set.